# How to eliminate dependency in Startup.cs Asp.net core?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control

I have UI, BLL and DAL layers in my project,
DAL and UI has a reference to BLL (Clean Architecture)

I want to wiring up implementation types to DAL, in the Startup class,
In order to wire up dependency injection in ConfigureServices in the Startup.cs file of the UI project, the project may need to reference the DAL project. How can I remove this dependency?

Comment: Your question is not clear. what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Using the clean architecture, the UI layer works with interfaces defined in the Application Core at compile time, and ideally should not have any knowledge of the implementation types defined in the Infrastructure layer.

Comment: At runtime, however, these implementation types will be required for the app to execute, so they will need to be present and wired up to the Application Core interfaces via dependency injection.

Comment: In order to wire up dependency injection in ConfigureServices in the Startup.cs file of the UI project, the project may need to reference the DAL project. How can I remove this dependency?